# toD() - Dynamic URI formation in camel 2.23 scheduled via Quartz

Tags: apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I'm newbie to Apache camel and wanted to Implement the toD() which is to dynamically frame the URI and add request params values from Beans..

Code snippet below -

from("quartz2://timer?cron=0+0/1+*+*+*+?")
.noAutoStartup().routeId(ROUTE_ID).log("Route Started")
.toD(http://localhost:3420/contextpath?from=${bean:bean.from} "+ "&size=${bean:bean.size}")
**.process(processor)**

Seems like, on every hit via Quartz the same URL is being triggered and hence I see duplicate values saved to DB. 
Please suggest why Dynamic uri is not working as expected.

**Am calling the processor, computing and setting the Bean values which i get from Response of Endpoint. But when the next time Quartz hits the url, the bean values are not updated and takes the default value
. Bean definition is usual getter setter, and registration is I have used Simple registry**

```
SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry ();
            // create CamelContext
            context = new DefaultCamelContext (simpleRegistry);

            simpleRegistry.put("bean", bean);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please post your bean-definition and registration code via [edit]. How do you change `from` or `size`? Thanks!

Comment: Please find the updated snippet, highlighted Bold.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use **dynamic URI** on a *camel-route* you must include your *variable* inside a ***Simple** expression*.

Since Camel **2.16.0** release endpoint implementation `toD()` supports the [Simple expression language](http://camel.apache.org/simple.html)  so you can define a [dynamic-URI as message-endpoint](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo):

```
from("quartz2://timer?cron=0+0/1+++*+?")
    .noAutoStartup()
    .routeId(ROUTE_ID)
    .log("Route Started")
    .toD( "http://localhost:3420/contextpath?from=${bean:bean.from}&size=${bean:bean.size}" );
```

So the expressions `${bean:bean.from}` and `${bean:bean.size}` should get directly *interpolated* by using  [Bean language](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html) inside your URI-string. This bean-component `bean:` tells Camel to get the bean registered with your specified name `bean` and call the specified methods `from` and `size`.

[Apache Camel: Rest DSL](https://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html#RestDSL-UsingDynamicto()), section **Using Dynamic to()** has also a note:

> **Note:** we need to use `.endRest()` to tell Camel where the route ends, so we can go back to the Rest DSL and continue defining REST services.

Otherwise you could implement that dynamic endpoint using simple inside your regular `to()`. See [Apache Camel: How to use a dynamic URI in to()](http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am consuming Rest endpoint, and want to change it every time via Quartz polling. Please suggest me in the above code, my Bean values are not persisted on every call.. so again and again it hits the same URL. And I have also tried with spel... with #{@bean.from} -> this is not working and bean is not resolved.. Please suggest what am doing wrong here